# Java Swing - JTable not showing

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel, flowlayout

I'm having some troubles with Java Swing.
I'm trying to make a frame with a control panel at the top with some buttons in it.
and below that i want a JTable to show

I've been trying but the table is not showing.
If I remove the controlPanel at the top, it sometimes shows and sometimes not.
The code that I use inside my constructor of my JTable is provided in the same application,
so it's no network error

```
public ServerMainFrame(GuiController gc){
    this.gc = gc;
    initGUI();
}

private void initGUI() {
    System.out.println("initiating GUI");
    createFrame();
    addContentPanel();
    addControls();
    //openPopUpServerSettings();
    addSongTable();
}

private void createFrame()
{
    this.setTitle("AudioBuddy 0.1");
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(800, 600);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

private void addContentPanel()
{
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    p.setSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    this.setContentPane(p);
}

private void addControls()
{
    JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel();
    controlPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    controlPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    controlPanel.setSize(700,100);

    // Buttons
    JButton play = new JButton("Play");
    JButton pause = new JButton("Pause");
    JButton stop = new JButton ("Stop");
    JButton next = new JButton("Next");
    JButton prev = new JButton("Previous");     
    controlPanel.add(play);
    controlPanel.add(pause);
    controlPanel.add(stop);
    controlPanel.add(next);
    controlPanel.add(prev);

    // Currently playing
    JLabel playing = new JLabel("Currently playing:");
    controlPanel.add(playing);

    JLabel current = new JLabel("Johnny Cash - Mean as Hell");
    controlPanel.add(current);

    this.getContentPane().add(controlPanel);
}

private void addSongTable()
{
    JTable songTable = new JTable(Server.getSongTableModel());
    songTable.setVisible(true);
    JPanel tablePanel = new JPanel();
    tablePanel.setVisible(true);
    tablePanel.add(songTable);
    songTable.repaint();
    this.getContentPane().add(tablePanel);

    JButton btnMulticastList = new JButton("send list to clients");
    btnMulticastList.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Server.MulticastPlaylist();
        }
    });

    getContentPane().add(btnMulticastList);
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> if I remove the controlPanel at the top, it sometimes shows and
>   sometimes not.

- everything is hidden in `Server.getSongTableModel()`, nobody knows without posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) with hardcoded value returns from
- GUI has issue with [Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)
- XxxModel loading data continiously with building GUi, then exception caused described problems

> The code that I use inside my constructor of my JTable is provided in
>   the same application, so it's no network error

- no idea what you talking about
- have to create an empty GUI, see [InitialTread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)
- showing GUI, then to start loading data to [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)
- then starting Workers Thread (Backgroung Task) from `SwingWorker` or (descr. Network issue) better `Runnable#Thread` (confortable for catching an exceptions and processing separate threads)
- output from `Runnable` to the Swing GUI must be wrapped into `invokeLater()`

Answer (score 5):

If you want controls at the top of your window, and the table filling the majority of the window, then I'd suggest you try using `BorderLayout` instead of `FlowLayout`. Create it like this...

```
private void addContentPanel()
{
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    p.setSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    this.setContentPane(p);
}
```

And add the components by specifying the location in the `BorderLayout`. In this case, the controls should be added to the top in their minimal size...

```
this.getContentPane().add(controlPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

And the table should be in the center, filling the remaining window space...

```
this.getContentPane().add(tablePanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

In your case, you also have a button at the bottom...

```
getContentPane().add(btnMulticastList,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

For the layout you're after, `BorderLayout` is much more appropriate. The benefit of using `BorderLayout` here is that the components should be automatically resized to the size of the window, and you're explicitly stating where each component resides, so panels shouldn't *not appear*.

It would also be my recommendation that you find an alternative to calling `getContentPane()` in all your methods. Maybe consider keeping a global variable for the main panel, like this...

```
private mainPanel;

private void addContentPanel()
{
    mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    mainPanel.setSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    this.setContentPane(mainPanel);
}
```

Then you can reference the panel directly when you want to `add()` components to it.

Finally, I'd also suggest using `GridLayout` for your controls, as it will allow you to place all your buttons in it, and they'll be the same size for consistency. Define it like this to allow 5 buttons in a horizontal alignment...

```
JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,1));
```

then you just add the buttons normally using `controlPanel.add(button)` and they'll be added to the next slot in the grid.

For more information, read about [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html) or [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html), or just see the Java Tutorial for a [Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to see what alternatives you have and the best one for your situation. In general, I try to avoid `FlowLayout`, as I find that there are other `LayoutManager`s that are more suitable in the majority of instances.